# How to make use of CustomData in the AuthenticationService

Tags: silverlight, forms-authentication, wcf-ria-services

The Login method of the Authentication service takes four arguments, the last being a string customData.

```
 public T Login(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, string customData);
```

I would like to know how this customData parameter can be used.  I don't see how it given the membership provider (since the membershipProvider ValidateUser takes only username and password), and I don't see how it is used by the AuthenticationBase Domain Service.

What I don't understand is this statement, from the documentation

> customData: Optional implementation-specific data. It is unused by
>   this base class.

If it is unused by the base class, how is a derived class suppose to use it, since the Login method is not virtual?

I need to pass additional authentication data as part of the login process and I was rather hoping that there would be a few extensible points on the server side that would make using the customData possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AuthenticationBase implements the IAuthentication interface and that is where the Login method is defined. If you create your own DomainService that implements IAuthentication directly instead of inheriting AuthenticationBase then you can use the customData.